# Heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ with $u(x,0)=0, u(1,t)=5t$, and $u_x(0,t)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ with $u(x,0)=0, u(1,t)=5t$, and $u_x(0,t)=0$

I saw this in [Japanese Q&A website](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14233457549) and tried to solve it but I couldn't.
So I am not sure that this can be solved analytically.

**What I tried**: From Wikipedia, I found a solution for $u(x,0)=0, u(0,t)=f(t)$ as:
$u(x,t)[f] = \int_0^t x/\sqrt{4\pi (t-s)^3}\ \exp(-x^2/4(t-s))\ f(s)\ ds$

In order to satisfy $u_x(0,t)=0$, I considered using symmetry: $u(x,t) = u(x+1,t)[f] + u(x-1,t)[f]$ for some $f$, but I couldn't adjust the result to satisfy $u(1,t)=5t$.

(My calculation)

$u(x,t)[f(t)=t] = \int_0^t x/\sqrt{4\pi (t-s)^3} \exp(-x^2/4(t-s))\ s\ ds \\\
 = [ (x^2/2+t) erf(x/2\sqrt{t-s}) - x\sqrt{t-s}/\sqrt{\pi}\ \exp(-x^2/4(t-s)) ]_0^t \\\
 = (x^2/2+t)(1-erf(x/2\sqrt{t})) - x\sqrt{t}/\sqrt{\pi}\ \exp(-x^2/4t)$

$u(x,t)[f(t)=1] = \int_0^t x/\sqrt{4\pi (t-s)^3}\ \exp(-x^2/4(t-s))\ ds \\\
 = [ erf(x/2\sqrt{t-s})  ]_0^t \\\
 = 1 - erf(x/2\sqrt{t})$

Comment: Alternatively, it seems like you can solve this with separation of variables and by splitting your solution into two parts $u = U + V$ where $V$ satisfies the boundary conditions which can be seen by inspection to be $V = 5 t + \frac{5}{2} (x^2 - 1)$. Note that without $U$, you cannot satisfy $u(x,0) = 0$ and so it is required, however, the impact of $U$ should tend rapidly to 0 and for $t \gg 1$, $u \to V$.

Answer (score -1):

From the comment by @Gregory, let $u=U+V, V=5t+\frac{5}{2}(x^2-1)$.
Then $U(x,t)$ should satisfies
$U(x,0) = \frac{5}{2}(1-x^2), U(1,t) = 0$

Now I can use the stable solutions:
$u(x,t)[n] = \exp(-n^2\pi^2t) \cos(nπx)$
and the Fourier series expansion
$1 - x^2 = 2/3 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n  \frac{4}{(nπ)^2} \cos(nπx)\ [-1\leq x\leq 1]$.

I obtained
$U(x,t) = 5/2\ (2/3 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{4}{(nπ)^2} u(x,t)[n])\\\
 = \frac{5}{3} - \frac{10}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} u(x,t)[n] )$,
and $u(x,t) = 5t + \frac{5}{2}x^2 - \frac{5}{6} - \frac{10}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \exp(-n^2\pi^2t) \cos(nπx)$.

Comment: $U$ has boundary conditions $U_x(0,t) = U(1,t) = 0$, your solution does not satisfy the boundary. It should be $\cos(k_n x)$ where $k_n = \frac{\pi}{2} (2n + 1)$.

Comment: I understood but I cannot construct $U(x,t)$ such that $U(x,0) = 5/2(1-x^2)$ by combining those $\exp(-k_n^2 t)\cos(k_n x)$.